# Как преобразовать "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LiveChartsCore.ISeries>" в "LiveCharts.SeriesCollection"? LiveCharts2

Tags: c#, wpf, коллекции, диаграммы, преобразование-типов

Не получается привести "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LiveChartsCore.ISeries>" в "LiveCharts.SeriesCollection".
Я хочу создать PieChart в коде, но на свойстве Series просит привести тип к определенному.

```
    public IEnumerable<ISeries> series { get; set; }

    public SeriesCollection Series;

    Заполнение Series

    series = new GaugeBuilder()
            .WithLabelsSize(50)
            .WithMaxColumnWidth(50)
            .AddValue(30, "", SKColors.Aqua, SKColors.White)
            .BuildSeries();

            Создание самого графика
            PieChart pieChart = new PieChart
            {
                HoverPushOut = 10,
                InnerRadius = 40,
                Series = series (вот здесь ошибка),
                DataContext = series,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 45, 10, 0),
                Height = 200,
                FontSize = 12,
                Width = 310,
                Foreground = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#ffffff"),



            };
```

Comment: Весь ваш код должен быть в XAML, это его задача. Если вы не пользуетесь XAML, то зачем тогда вам WPF? Ведь WPF это именно XAML и привязки.  Касательно того, как правильно использовать LiveCharts - у них есть куча примеров, с подробным кодом, который показывает как и что использовать.

Comment: Проблема в том что, мне необходимо создавать графики именно из кода, чтобы подставлять другие значения и создать другие графики.

Comment: И где тут проблема? Данные в одном месте, а вид в другом. Ваши данные, это как раз коллекция `series `, в которую вы просто вносите новые данные, а все остальное (вид, цвет, шрифт, размер, и прочее) - это часть XAML (UI).

Comment: График то создается, но данные в нем не отображаются в окне, хотя сам элемент есть. И ошибку я устранил,             pieChart.Series = new SeriesCollection(gaugeBuilder);

Comment: Но данные так  и не отображаются.

Comment: Вы меня вообще не слушаете. Ну чтож, дело ваше...

Comment: Я честно не понимаю, я в WPF всего 1 неделю :(

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб говорить "не понимаю", лучше бы задали конкретный вопрос, что именно вы не понимаете. Я вроде все понятным языком написал - У вас не должно быть создание контролов в C# коде, не должно быть обращение к ним через имя. Научитесь использовать базу, а именно XAML и Binding, поймите как с ними работать, как взаимодействовать, как отделить данные от UI, это прям базовые понятия, по которым дальше весь проект сроится. Например вот документация [графиков](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Pie%20or%20Doughnut), вы видите там `new PieChart`? Нет, ибо он в XAML (`<lvc:PieChart`).

Comment: У меня тоже аллергия на View в C#, по нескольким причинам 1) XAML компактнее и понятнее 2) косяков меньше 3) привязки данных - действительно то что обязательно стоит знать в WPF, экономят кучу времени и делают код сильно короче